# Can bytes32 be changed to a string in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I was wondering if it is possible to convert a bytes32 to a string in solidity like this,
I want an input `bytes32 input = 0x74657374`
and an output of `string output = "0x74657374"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you wouldn't want to do that normally.

Generally, don't burden a contract with a client's job. It isn't especially easy to do because `bytes` and `string` are variable length and therefore require setting aside a word for length. The length of `bytes32` requires no such extra internal organization.

Have a look over here: [How to convert bytes32 to string?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56319/how-to-convert-bytes32-to-string)

Hope it helps.